How to replace true/false by yes/no?
I am making a quite big Shiny App. I am using the package DT for rendering tables.
In a few of them, I have logical variables, which are displayed in the front by "true" and "false" by default.
I am trying to replace those by "Yes" and "No" without changing the logical type of my variables and with minimal code. Thus, I need a way to change this only on display.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

It would be helpful to add some sample data and code. There are certainly ways to do this. For example, you could write some js to change the text of certain elements once they are rendered. I don't know why you would, though. Why can't you just create an extra column and display that instead of your logical column? The data can't be that large if you're rendering it in an html table.
